# How to apply Optimizer on Variable in Chainer?

Tags: python, chainer

Here is an example in Pytorch:

```
optimizer = optim.Adam([modifier_var], lr=0.0005)
```

And here in Tensorflow:

```
self.train = self.optimizer.minimize(self.loss, var_list=[self.modifier])
```

But Chainer's optimizers only can use on 'Link', how can I apply Optimizer on Variable in Chainer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, there is no way to directly assign `chainer.Variable` (even nor `chainer.Parameter`) to `chainer.Optimizer`.

The following is some redundant explanation.

First, I re-define `Variable` and `Parameter` to avoid confusion.

`Variable` is (1) `torch.Tensor` in PyTorch v4, (2) `torch.autograd.Variable` in PyTorch v3, and (3) `chainer.Variable` in Chainer v4.
`Variable` is an object who holds two tensors; `.data` and `.grad`. It is the necessary and sufficient condition, so `Variable` is not necessarily a learnable parameter, which is a target of the optimizer.

In both libraries, there is another class `Parameter`, which is similar but not the same with `Variable`. `Parameter` is `torch.autograd.Parameter` in Pytorch and `chainer.Parameter` in Chainer.
`Parameter` must be a learnable parameter and should be optimized.

Therefore, there should be no case to register `Variable` (not `Parameter`) to `Optimizer` (although PyTorch allows to register `Variable` to `Optimizer`: this is just for backward compatibility).

Second, in PyTorch `torch.nn.Optimizer` directly optimizes `Parameter`, but in Chainer `chainer.Optimizer` DOES NOT optimize `Parameter`: instead, `chainer.UpdateRule` does. The `Optimizer` just registers `UpdateRule`s to `Parameter`s in a `Link`.

Therefore, it is only natural that `chainer.Optimizer` does not receive `Parameter` as its arguments, because it is just a "delivery-man" of `UpdateRule`.

If you want to attach different `UpdateRule` for each `Parameter`, you should directly create an instance of `UpdateRule` subclass, and attach it to the `Parameter`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example to learn regression task by `MyChain` MLP model using `Adam` optimizer in Chainer.

```
from chainer import Chain, Variable

# Prepare your model (neural network) as `Link` or `Chain`
class MyChain(Chain):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyChain, self).__init__(
            l1=L.Linear(None, 30),
            l2=L.Linear(None, 30),
            l3=L.Linear(None, 1)
        )

    def __call__(self, x):
        h = self.l1(x)
        h = self.l2(F.sigmoid(h))
        return self.l3(F.sigmoid(h))

model = MyChain()

# Then you can instantiate optimizer
optimizer = chainer.optimizers.Adam()

# Register model to optimizer (to indicate which parameter to update)
optimizer.setup(model)

# Calculate loss, and update parameter as follows.
def lossfun(x, y):
    loss = F.mean_squared_error(model(x), y)
    return loss

# this iteration is "training", to fit the model into desired function.
for i in range(300):
    optimizer.update(lossfun, x, y)
```

So in summary, you need to `setup` the `model`, after that you can use `update` function to calculate loss and update `model`'s parameter.
The above code comes from [here](http://corochann.com/chainer-basic-module-introduction-2-1115.html#Optimizer)

Also, there are other way to write training code using `Trainer` module. For more detailed tutorial of Chainer, please refer below

- [chainer-handson](https://github.com/mitmul/chainer-handson/blob/master/README_en.md)
- [deep-learning-tutorial-with-chainer](https://github.com/corochann/deep-learning-tutorial-with-chainer)